# selenium few WebDrivers one window [JAVA]

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have problem with selenium JAVA.
I have something like this:

```
WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
```

How to open driver1 and driver2 in one window and two tabs?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

`Robot r = new Robot();`

`r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);`

`r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);`

`r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);`

`r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);`

Comment: Only create one instance of Webdriver

Comment: is a way that make two webdrivers? Or make one webdriver perform different tasks at the same time?

Comment: Yes you can make one webdriver perform 2 task
oDriver.get("http://site2.com");
--Perform operation on this site then
oDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
--perform operation on 2nd site